# Обращение к изображениям

Tags: javascript, dom

Каким образом обратиться к любому изображению, используемому на странице (даже указанном в  css)?

Есть `document.images`, но он содержит изображения только с тегов `<img>`. А требуется возможность обращаться к любым изображениям, используемым на странице вне зависимости от того, где они были указаны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. document.images
2. document.styleSheets[...].cssRules[...].backgroundImage
3. document.all[...].style.backgroundImage
4. document.all[...].currentStyle.backgroundImage

Вероятно это не все, но для начала хватит, правда? ;)

Из скриптов достать сложнее, т.е. заранее не зная где искать, никак.